# Content Security Policy frame-ancestors incorrectly blocks on safari from filesystem

Tags: cordova, safari, content-security-policy

I am developing a cordova app for android & ios when I noticed that the iframe used in my app was not loading correctly on ios. As it turns out, although the frame-ancestors HTTP header was correctly set from the web server, safari will incorrectly refuse to load the iframe if opened through the filesystem.

`Refused to load http://to-delete-test.azurewebsites.net/ because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.`

The CSP Header from the test page is:

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors * data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss:`

An example HTML file that shows this error (must be loaded from a filesystem):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        iframe {
            height: 100vh; width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://to-delete-test.azurewebsites.net"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can modify the page headers to allow loading of my site through an iframe?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean under "open through the filesystem", but I know that `frame-ancestors` directive definitely [does not support `data:` `blob:`](https://csplite.com/csp/test398/) and `ws:`, `wss:` scheme-sources. Looks like `about:` and `filesystem:` are not supported too. Anyway your `frame-ancestors` should restrict nothing. Check in the Dev Tool -> Network -> Response Header what CSP do you actually have.

Comment: @granty thanks for your reply. "Open through the filesystem" refers to opening a html file served from the device's filesystem, so the url would be something like `file:///path/to/file/index.html`. On safari on iOS or OSX, if there is a `frame-ancestors` CSP header it appears that the frame will not load no matter what the value of the header is, even with `*` included. Cordova apps load the webpage from its filesystem, so it appears there is no way to safely allow a cordova app to load from a frame while also restricting other sites from loading the page in a frame.

Answer (score 1):

After additional info in comments the situation becomes clear.
Due to security reasons the file:-URLs like `file:///path/to/file/index.html` are prohibited to be opened in nested browsing context (iframe, object, embed) regardless of CSP. Also `<a href='file:///path/to/file/index.html'>` is prohibited to navigate.

You cannot get around this limitation by using CSP. Moreover, the `frame-ancestors` directive does not supports non-network schemes for it loses its meaning.

Also looks like the console message shown belongs Safari and it's misleading a little bit.
Chrome should show real violation reason like: *Refused to load iframe **file:///path/to/file/index.html** because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:...*.

Note. Chrome browser allows to access local filesystem using `file:///` scheme in case of loading images/styles/scripts etc:

```
<img src='file:///c:/img.png'>
<script src='file:///c:/scripr.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='file:///c:/style.css'>
```

and even supports the [`file:` scheme in CSP](https://csplite.com/csp/test361/#file_scheme).
But AFAIK browser extensions should not use direct access via file:///-URLs. Extensions have to use own packaged resources or the [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface)